# Print API for Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a Chrome Extension API that I can use to interact with the printing options for a page?  I've checked [Chrome's extension API's,](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) but I can't seem to find anything on interacting with printing options in any way.

Is interacting with printer options possible using Chrome Extensions?

Comment: I don't think the Chrome extension API provides ways to control printing the way you'd need. See the related issues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631032/printing-a-page-to-different-printers-in-a-web-app

Comment: Yeah, I'd read that question when checking out the availability in Firefox.  It's unfortunate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, no, there is no such API currently.

There are, it seems, [vague plans for such an API](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450263) in Chrome Apps, but nothing concrete yet as of 2015-04-16.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [chrome.printerProvider](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider) API (added in version 44).

Comment: As the API name already suggests, this API merely allows extensions to provide a printing service. It does not allow extensions to modify the printer settings for print jobs to other printers.